# Nginx Plus not streaming HLS

Tags: nginx, http-live-streaming

I have installed Nginx Plus and configured HLS for streaming. While requesting the `m3u8` file I'm getting the error:

```
2015/09/29 13:32:34 [error] 5814#5814: *1 open() "/usr/video/hls/CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

The `m3u8` file has the following contents:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=545600,RESOLUTION=416x234,CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"
/usr/video/hls/myvideo_low.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1755600,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"
/usr/video/hls/myvideo_high.m3u8
```

The Nginx configuration is:

```
location /hls {
      root   /usr/video;
      hls;
      hls_fragment            5s;
      hls_buffers             10 10m;
      hls_mp4_buffer_size     1m;
      hls_mp4_max_buffer_size 5m;
      types {
           application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
           video/mp2t ts;
      }
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';
}
```

In the browser I am getting a warning:
 "No TS Fragments found".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to dynamically create the `ts` segments from a static file like an `mp4` the filename and extension must be present in the `m3u8` playlist filename:

`myvideo_high.mp4.m3u8` for `myvideo_high.mp4`

For:

`myvideo_high.m3u8`

it assumes the segments already exist.

---

The [Serving Media with NGINX Plus](https://www.nginx.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Serving-Media-with-NGINX-Plus.pdf) whitepaper shows an example for a manually created `m3u8` variant playlist which **is incorrect due to page formatting (line wrapping)**:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=545600,RESOLUTION=416x234,
CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"
/hls/myvideo_low.mp4.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1755600,RESOLUTION=640x360,
CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"
/hls/myvideo_high.mp4.m3u8
```

THe `#EXT-X-STREAM-INF` information should be on a single line (no new-line characters):

```
 #EXTM3U
 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=545600,RESOLUTION=416x234,CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"
 /hls/myvideo_low.mp4.m3u8
 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1755600,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"
 /hls/myvideo_high.mp4.m3u8
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but #EXT-X-STREAM-INF is already there on a single line .

Comment: Double-check because it tries to open `/usr/video/hls/CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"` which is consistent with a malformed playlist.

Comment: I have verified and its configured properly . Do we need to create  /hls/myvideo_low.mp4.m3u8 file manually or nginx server will do it for us

Comment: It should create them automatically. Try if it works first with a simple playlist. Put a `test.mp4` in `/usr/video` and see if `test.mp4.m3u8` plays.

Comment: I am able to stream it for simple playlist if .ts files are already present and .m3u8 file is pointing to it but dynamic generation of m3u8 and ts file is not happening from master m3u8

Comment: I am getting this message on browser console WARN:No TS fragments found in http://ip:99/usr/video/hls/myvideo_low.m3u8

Comment: Dynamic generation only works for a static input like `mp4`.  It checks if the extension is present in the playlist name (ie: /hls/myvideo_low.mp4.m3u8). You master playlist's filename doesn't contain the extension so you must provide the `ts` segments yourself.

Comment: I have renamed master playlist file to hls.mp4.m3u8 is that what you are saying? i want nginx to generate playlista nd segment file dynamically

Comment: I updated the answer. If you have a file like `test.mp4` the playlists **in the variant playlist** should be named like `test_high.mp4.m3u8`. See the example from the whitepaper in my initial answer. You can name the variant playlist whatever you like.

Comment: My file names are test.mp4 and master playlist name is test.mp4.m3u8 and internally its referring to test_low.mp4.m3u8 and test_high.mp4.m3u8  But still no luck .

Comment: No, don't put the extension in the master. Name it just `test.m3u8`.